# How do I read a CFExpress Card with Adobe Bridge Photo Downloader?

Tags: import, cfcard, adobe-bridge

I have a Lexar 128GB CFExpress type B card for capturing images on my camera. I am running Adobe Bride 12 on a MacBook Pro running Monterey.

When I plug the CFExpress card reader (UNITEK) into my computer I can see the card in the finder. However in Adobe Bride Photo Downloader it says

> None Detected - No Device Found

I have read numerous complaints about this issue on message boards, but none of them explain the issue or offer a solution that has worked for me. The favorite answer is

**Allow Full Disk Access for Adobe Bride**

[image: Full Disk Access]

I have enabled Full Disk Access and rebooted. Still no luck.

Why is this an issue and what is the solution? I know that I can drag the photos from the disk to a local folder the finder but that is far from ideal as I like to rename the photos and convert them to DNG when I ingest them.

I would like to know why this is happening and how to resolve it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac is seeing the CFexpress card/reader as a HDD and not as removable storage.
But if you connect the camera (with card in it) via USB it should see it as an external device. And that should allow you to download the images directly using bridge.

Comment: That is correct. I have been able to download that way. It helps to understand that the Mac sees it as an HDD though. My objective with a card reader is to avoid the wear and tear of opening up the side panel on my camera. Over time it will wear out the sealable flap. Thanks for the insights.

Comment: Other programs besides bridge (e.g. Lightroom) will also work. Have you tried the Adobe DNG Converter? https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/using/adobe-dng-converter.html

Comment: Yes. I have used DNG Converter. It converts NEF to DNG fine and also renames the files. The one sweet spot with Photo Downloader is that it converts the files to DNG and renames the files with one extra touch: you can rename the file using the Create Date. So it uses the create date, not just today's date, regardless of when you ingest the images.

Answer (score -1):

Use Nikon NX Studio, it's free and better than Photo Downloader.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about how it is better? It would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: It's free, download it, try it, best of all it works with cfExpress cards......that's the real bonus!!

Comment: Okay; I can give it a shot. Expanding your answer a bit with a good download link would be great, too.